# First lookahead then look for closest matching capture group behind the lookahead match. RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a full text with line separated strings. Lines starting with '%' are titles and lines starting with '>' contain the text I want to look for my my query in. If my query is found I want to return the nearest title above it. Here is the expression I tried myself:

```
import re
query = "ABCDE"
full_text = "%EFGHI\r>XXXXX\r>XXXXX\r%IWANT\r>XXXXX\r>ABCDE"
re.search("%(.*?)\r(?=>.*{})".format(query), full_text).group(0)
```

I want this code block to return the string:

```
> 'IWANT'
```

As this is the closest title above the query. However, it returns:

```
> 'EFGHI'
```

I guess it makes sense, since 'EFGHI' is the first element matching the search pattern. Is there a way to first lookahead for my query and then look back for the nearest title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest matching all parts with `\r>...` that have no `%`  after `\r` before the `ABCDE` value to get the right title:

```
r"%([^\r]*)(?=(?:\r(?!%)[^\r]*)*\r>[^\r]*{})".format(query)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/l1yiYp)

**Pattern details**:

- `%` - a `%` char
- `([^\r]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than CR chars
- `(?=(?:\r(?!%)[^\r]*)*\r>[^\r]*ABCDE)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, must match the following sequence of patterns:

  - `(?:\r(?!%)[^\r]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of CR not followed with `%` and then followed with  zero or more chars other than CR chars
  - `\r>` - a CR char and `>`
  - `[^\r]*` - zero or more chars other than CR chars
  - `ABCDE` - a literal char sequence

Comment: I think it simpler: r'%([^%>]+)[^%]*?\r>{}'.format(query)

Comment: @kantal I see your variant is working, but I am not sure that `XXX` parts do not contain `%` or `>`, and `ABCDE` probably does not have to appear right after `>`.